# How to debug 500 error in Ajax response

Tags: php, ajax, error-handling

I'm trying to debug a sporadic 500 error which users occasionally get when filling out form sections on my site. Whenever it happens, I try to recreate their environment and fill out the form exactly as they have done, but can never recreate the issue. I have checked my application logs for the framework I am using, but they report nothing related to the error. I'm hoping someone here might be able to help me catch this. This is where the 500 error is sometimes happening and this triggers the error which users report:

```
//In jquery AJAX function, which submits data to PHP form for processing
error: function(data,transport){ 
$.validationEngine.debug("error in ajax response: "+data.status+" "+transport) 
}
```

Is there a way for me to try and catch what the exact error is here?

Comment: If it 'sometimes happens in AJAX' then test if it should sometimes happen outside AJAX too. Can you recreate that AJAX script call in a separate browser window and refresh-test it to see if it throws a 500?

Comment: You need to look at your web server's logs rather than those left by the framework. There's a chance that the server is sending back a 500 error before the request even hits your application.

Comment: The problem is I can't recreate the error, either using an AJAX call or not to call the PHP script. I need to catch the error response from the PHP script being called, but I never get an error when trying to recreate the user issue, i.e same OS/browser/form answers

Comment: The Apache error logs for the site have very little - unless I'm looking in the wrong place. I'm on CentOS, ran `locate error_log` and got an error_log.txt file in my vhosts directory for my site, but this just contained a 302 message log, nothing else. I also tried `locate error | grep mysite`

Answer (score 1):

As far as AJAX just reads server response status and doesn't create it, you should read for 'error.log'. As useful info you can look into firebug for sending data.